# JOIN on row by which row in the join query has the MAX/MIN value of all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, join, max

If the query I want to join on returns:

```
IDApplication  ContactDate  CInfo
1              01/06/2016   pie
1              10/01/2016   cake
1              03/02/2015   banana
2              03/06/2016   cake
2              23/12/2015   apple



IDApplication  ReplyDate    RInfo
1              30/05/2016   circle
1              03/05/2016   square
1              04/02/2015   triangle
1              14/01/2016   pentagon
2              04/06/2016   square
2              01/02/2016   pentagon
2              10/06/2016   circle
```

I need this to be returned:

```
IDApplication  ContactDate  CInfo       ReplyDate    RInfo    
1              01/06/2016   pie         NULL         NULL
1              10/01/2016   cake        30/05/2016   circle
1              03/02/2015   banana      04/02/2015   triangle
2              03/06/2016   cake        10/06/2016   square
2              23/12/2015   apple       01/02/2016   pentagon
```

I need it to return the second table/query info where its date is larger than any corresponding application date in the first table, but which isn't larger than any following date in the first table.

So for the first record above, it is NULL because there is no reply info with a date after 01/06/2016 in the reply table (so no reply has been made), but the second record has the reply date of 30/05/2016 as that is the largest reply date for that application. More importantly for the 5th record the reply date is 01/02/2016, this date is larger than the contact date but not THE largest reply date for application 2 which is 10/06/2016, but as another contact date for application 2 is in between these 2 it needs to show the largest date before the following contact date.

This is logic which is making my brain hurt.

I've gotten as far as joining the second query on where reply date is larger than the contact date, but that causes it to make rows appear for all dates larger.

I need to join on the record with a date larger than the base tables date but of these the largest where it isn't larger than the next largest base table date.

Comment: Does the second table have a surrogate key?

Comment: Is this a theoretical exercise or a real world problem? It's most likely possible to get the join working the way you specified it. But I doubt it's the right way to deal with the information you have. If this is a real world problem, better to reorganise the information or the query.

Comment: This is real world, the worst part is the 2 "tables" I refer to are actually the same table, this part of our db is a joke. (Theres a column stating if its contact or reply, so for the sake of this it can be illustrated as 2 tables)

Our db is massive, we generated a relationship diagram of it and it only managed to render 1/20th, it was abstract art. So we can't change the table itself, too messy. 

I can see it being feasible if I can do an IF within the join at the AND x,y,z stage

Comment: This is a classic gaps and islands problem. I do not have the mental fortitude to solve this one today, however, here is one of my answers to a similar problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207375/user-sessions-based-on-user-activity/36208213#36208213

Comment: I'm not sure that the joining criteria you gave us is sufficient to ensure that a given record in the first table will always map one-to-one with a record in the second table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach to problems like this is typically to break them into small steps, each of which I can implement as a CTE, so I get something that's pretty easy to read through and understand. I can always try to collapse it into fewer steps later if need be. Here's a possible solution. See the comments for an explanation of how it works.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Set up the sample data from the question.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
declare @Contact table (IDApplication int, ContactDate date, CInfo varchar(32));
declare @Reply table (IDApplication int, ReplyDate date, RInfo varchar(32));

insert @Contact values
    (1, '2016-06-01',' pie'),
    (1, '2016-01-10', 'cake'),
    (1, '2015-02-03', 'banana'),
    (2, '2016-06-03', 'cake'),
    (2, '2015-12-23', 'apple');
insert @Reply values
    (1, '2016-05-30', 'circle'),
    (1, '2016-05-03', 'square'),
    (1, '2015-02-04', 'triangle'),
    (1, '2016-01-14', 'pentagon'),
    (2, '2016-06-04', 'square'),
    (2, '2016-02-01', 'pentagon'),
    (2, '2016-06-10', 'circle');

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Step 1: Sequence each group of contacts by contact date.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
with OrderedContactCTE as
(
    select
        *,
        [Sequence] = row_number() over (partition by IDApplication order by ContactDate)
    from
        @Contact
),

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Step 2: Match each contact with the subsequent contact (where one exists)
--         having the same IDApplication value. The date of the subsequent
--         contact will act as the upper bound on reply dates that are valid for
--         the original contact. Assign each contact a unique identifier that
--         we'll use in the following step.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PairedContactCTE as
(
    select
        UniqueID = row_number() over (order by Contact.IDApplication, Contact.[Sequence]),
        Contact.IDApplication,
        Contact.ContactDate,
        Contact.CInfo,
        NextContactDate = NextContact.ContactDate
    from
        OrderedContactCTE Contact
        left join OrderedContactCTE NextContact on
            Contact.IDApplication = NextContact.IDApplication and
            Contact.[Sequence] = NextContact.[Sequence] - 1
),

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Step 3: Match every contact with all replies that are strictly after the 
--         original contact date and, where applicable, strictly before the 
--         subsequent contact date. For each unique contact, sequence the 
--         replies in reverse order by reply date.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OrderedResponseCTE as
(
    select
        Contact.*,
        Reply.ReplyDate,
        Reply.RInfo,
        [Sequence] = row_number() over (partition by Contact.UniqueID order by Reply.ReplyDate desc)
    from
        PairedContactCTE Contact
        left join @Reply Reply on
            Contact.IDApplication = Reply.IDApplication and
            Contact.ContactDate < Reply.ReplyDate and
            (
                Contact.NextContactDate is null or
                Contact.NextContactDate > Reply.ReplyDate
            )
)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Step 4: Finally, select each contact and the date/info of the latest reply
--         which is an eligible match for that contact.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
select
    IDApplication,
    ContactDate,
    CInfo,
    ReplyDate,
    RInfo
from 
    OrderedResponseCTE 
where 
    [Sequence] = 1;
```

Comment: Fabulous! Works like a treat, gonna spend a while actually trying to understand it now :]

Comment: As a note, due to the size of the data I'm dealing with, I've altered it to use temp tables instead of CTE, as the results are in the thousands, and this is for a report which may be queried multiple times a day.

Answer (score 1):

After about 15 minutes of psychological torment I was able to churn out this query.  The only caviat is that I am not sure that the join condition will only match a single record in each case.  I suspect there is another join condition which you did not explicitly mention.

```
SELECT t1.IDApplication, t1.ContactDate, t1.CInfo,
    t2.ReplyDate, t2.RInfo
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN
table2 t2
    ON t1.IDApplication = t2.IDApplication AND
       t2.ReplyDate > t1.ContactDate AND
       t2.ReplyDate < (SELECT MIN(t.ContactDate)
                       FROM table1 t
                       WHERE t.ContactDate > t1.ContactDate AND
                             t.IDApplication = t1.IDApplication)
```

Comment: Hmmm, this brings through the correct number of rows, but only info from table1, nothing from table2 can be brought though, only NULL, doing table2.* only returns NULL for all fields. 

But you've gotten further in 15mins than I have all week.

Comment: You need Gordon Linoff for a question like this, or possibly that horse whose name I can't seem to remember.

Comment: This solution is getting close to the mark. It needs an extra join clause in the subquery at the very least:

                 (SELECT MIN(table1.ContactDate)
                       FROM table1
                       WHERE table1.ContactDate > t1.ContactDate
                       AND table1.IDApplication = t1.IDApplication )

Comment: It will also need a further subquery. At the moment, if you have a time sequence of contact, reply, reply, reply contact, the main query will produce three rows for the first contact (one per reply). There should be a subquery to restrict t2 where there is a subsequent reply coming in before the next contact date.

Comment: This second subquery is the challenging part because I can't easily see it.

Comment: In Oracle I would write the second subquery as: AND NOT EXISTS ( select null FROM table2 t2_sub WHERE t2_sub.IDApplication = t2.IDApplication AND t2_sub.ReplyDate > t2.ReplyDate AND t2_sub.ReplyDate < (SELECT MIN(t.ContactDate)
                       FROM table1 t
                       WHERE t.ContactDate > t1.ContactDate AND
                             t.IDApplication = t1.IDApplication) ). ----------- You would then rewrite the MIN(t.ContactDate) parts as something like NVL(MIN(t.ContactDate),'31-dec-9999') to handle the case where you're at the last contact already for this ID.

Comment: I need to learn gaps and islands.  This is as far as I can go now, but a guru will get this right later.  Feel free to edit my post or turn it into a community wiki.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a SQL Server instance to test. Let me know how close this gets (extension of Tim's solution)

```
SELECT c1.IDApplication, c1.ContactDate, c1.CInfo, r1.ReplyDate, r1.RInfo
FROM contact_table c1
LEFT JOIN
reply_table r1
    ON c1.IDApplication = r1.IDApplication AND
       r1.ReplyDate > c1.ContactDate AND
       r1.ReplyDate < ( SELECT isnull(MIN(c2.ContactDate),'31-DEC-9999')
                       FROM contact_table c2
                       WHERE c2.ContactDate > c1.ContactDate AND
                             c2.IDApplication = c1.IDApplication ) AND
       NOT EXISTS ( SELECT null
                    FROM reply_table r2
                    WHERE r2.IDApplication = r1.IDApplication AND
                          r2.ReplyDate > r1.ReplyDate AND
                          r2.ReplyDate < ( SELECT isnull(MIN(c2.ContactDate),'31-DEC-9999')
                                           FROM contact_table c2
                                           WHERE c2.ContactDate > c1.ContactDate AND
                                                 c2.IDApplication = c1.IDApplication ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you record rely on some data from record above its better to implement some stored procedure logic. Something like this:

```
/*
CREATE TABLE App (Id INT, ContractDate DATETIME, CInfo VARCHAR(100))

CREATE TABLE Reply (Id INT, ReplyDate DATETIME, RInfo VARCHAR(100))

INSERT App SELECT 1, '06/01/2016',' pie'
INSERT App SELECT 1, '01/10/2016', 'cake'
INSERT App SELECT 1, '02/03/2015', 'banana'
INSERT App SELECT 2, '06/03/2016', 'cake'
INSERT App SELECT 2, '12/23/2015', 'apple'


INSERT Reply SELECT 1, '05/30/2016', 'circle'
INSERT Reply SELECT 1, '05/03/2016', 'square'
INSERT Reply SELECT 1, '02/04/2015', 'triangle'
INSERT Reply SELECT 1, '01/14/2016', 'pentagon'
INSERT Reply SELECT 2, '06/04/2016', 'square'
INSERT Reply SELECT 2, '02/01/2016', 'pentagon'
INSERT Reply SELECT 2, '06/10/2016', 'circle'
*/
--SELECT * FROM App
DECLARE @AppReply TABLE (Id INT, ContractDate DATETIME, CInfo VARCHAR(100), ReplyDate DATETIME, RInfo VARCHAR(100))

DECLARE
    @Id INT,
    @PrevId INT,
    @ContractDate DATETIME,
    @PrevContractDate DATETIME,
    @CInfo VARCHAR(100)

DECLARE appcursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
SELECT Id, ContractDate, CInfo FROM App  

OPEN appcursor  

FETCH NEXT FROM appcursor   
INTO @Id, @ContractDate, @CInfo

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

    IF(@Id != @PrevId)
        SET @PrevContractDate = NULL

    INSERT @AppReply (Id, ContractDate, CInfo)
    SELECT TOP 1 @Id, @ContractDate, @CInfo

    UPDATE @AppReply SET ReplyDate = R.ReplyDate, RInfo = R.RInfo
    FROM @AppReply AR
    LEFT JOIN Reply R ON R.Id = AR.Id
        AND R.ReplyDate > AR.ContractDate AND R.ReplyDate < ISNULL(@PrevContractDate, DATEADD(DD, 1, R.ReplyDate))
    WHERE AR.Id = @Id AND AR.CInfo = @CInfo

    SET @PrevContractDate = @ContractDate
    SET @PrevId = @Id

    FETCH NEXT FROM appcursor   
    INTO @Id, @ContractDate, @CInfo 
END   
CLOSE appcursor;  
DEALLOCATE appcursor;  

SELECT * FROM @AppReply
```

Hope this helps.
P.S.: this query was written fast. Sorry for poor logic in it.